# Unable to pass the value using sendkeys in Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to send any value to my application using webdriver. I'm able to click on the element.  But `SendKeys` is not working, execution stops once I click on a `Textbox`.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='atgf']/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='atgf']/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]")).sendkeys("abc");
```

Comment: First of all, show the contents of the `table`. Also, what do you mean by `not working`? Any errors?

Comment: Is it text field or something which will except keys.A submit button cannot except "abc".

Comment: Thanks Alecxe.Execution stops after clicking on the element(textbox). Is ther any method other then SendKeys to pass String.

Comment: @user3905396 If you don't invest some time to write a proper question, where you provide what you have tried and where you have failed, you will properbly never get a for you helpful answer. Please also keep in mind that questions on StackOverflow should also help other people with a similar problem and not only you. [help/how-to-ask]

Comment: @rekire : Here I clearly mentioned the Question that Sendkeys option is not working where as Click option is working for a web element(Textbox). This means that , Selenium Identifying the Element where as It is not sending r passing value into it. If you need further details please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following way,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("...")).sendkeys(new String[]{"abc"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Thread.sleep(time in ms) before entering the value in the text field. Sometimes that may be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Java compiler is  set to 1.5 version change it to 1.6.

This is a very common problem with the Java compiler. 
All you need to do is just set the Java compiler 1.6 from 1.5.

To change the Java compiler version, complete the following steps:

1. In the Project Explorer view of the Java EE perspective, right-click
   the project and then select Properties.
2. Select the Project Facets page in the in the Properties window. This page lists the facets in the project and their versions.
3. Click Modify Project.
4. Double click the version number next to theJava facet to select a different level of Java compiler.
5. Click Finish to close the Modify Faceted Project window and then click OK.